# How to print hexadecimal values in "0x" format in C

Tags: c, hex, printf, format-specifiers

I am trying to print hexadecimal values in C.

A simple known program to print hexadecimal value...( Using `%x` or `%X` format specifier)

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned int num = 10;
    printf("hexadecimal value of %u is %x\n", num, num);
}
```

Output: `hexadecimal value of 10 is a`

Instead of getting output as `a`, I need to get output as `0xa` in hexadecimal format (making if more explicit for the user that the value in expresses in hexadecimal format).

Comment: `%#x` also works: see https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf

Comment: I don't want to use ox before %x. 

%x in gcc (11.4.0) compiler it doesn't expects unsigned int. it works fine.

Comment: @TomKarzes Could please share me the link where i can see the documentation correctly...

Comment: @ASWIN Look at the [man page for printf(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html)  Scroll down to where `o, u, x, X` are documented.  It says *The unsigned int argument is converted to unsigned octal (o), unsigned decimal (u), or unsigned hexadecimal (x and X) notation.*  The `#` modifier is documented above that, under "flag characters".

Comment: int main()
{
 unsigned int num = 10;
 printf("hexadecimal value of %d is %x\n",num,num);

is now am i right? @TomKarzes Thanks for making me to find it out

Comment: @ASWIN No, because `%d` expects a signed `int`. You could use `%u` instead of `%d`, which prints an unsigned decimal value. So you could do `unsigned int num = 10;` then `printf("%u %#x\n", num, num);` That would be strictly correct, since both format specifiers expect an `unsigned int`.

Comment: @ASWIN Why "I don't want to use ox before %x"?  `printf("hexadecimal value of %u is 0x%X\n", num, num);` is very readable.

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/a/76856937/22110125

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 ways to achieve this:

- using `0x%x`, which ensures even `0` is printed as `0x0`.  `0x%X` is the only solution to print the `x` in lowercase and the number with uppercase hexadecimal digits.  Note however that you cannot use the width prefix as the padding spaces will appear between the `0x` and the digits: `printf(">0x%4x<", 100)` will output `>0x  64<`
- using `%#x`, which adds the `0x` prefix if the number is non zero and is compatible with the width prefix: `printf(">%#6x<", 100)` will output `>  0x64<`, but both `printf(">%#06x<", 100)` and `printf(">0x%04x<", 100)` will output `>0x0064<`.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers have explained well how the "0x" prefix can be obtained.

I would like to add that hexadecimal numbers are often used with a fixed width (e.g. 2 or 4 digits). This can be obtained as follows:

```
  printf("0x%04x", num);
```

which will print e.g.

```
  0x0054
```